# unable to import from path mentioned in exports of library's package.json in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

My project tscofig look like this.

I know that tscofig can affect the behaviour of project import.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "es2016.array.include",
      "es2019.object",
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
}
```

the library i exported path tsconfig.json look like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "es5",
      "dom"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "preserveSymlinks": true,
    "preserveWatchOutput": true,
    "pretty": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "mocha"
    ],
    "rootDir": "./packages"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "packages/testcases/**",
    "packages/tests/**"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./packages/**/src.ts/*.ts",
    "./packages/**/src.ts/**/*.ts",
    "./packages/**/thirdparty.d.ts",
  ],
}
```

my react native project unable to import the exported path. it is trying to find the actual path  not trying to resolve from exports of package. although my ide is able to undestand.

in metro serve i get error library/exportedPathA not found in node_modules?